# How do i echo multiple lines of input with this code?

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

I want the user to enter an animal and it go to the line below their previous input.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Will Proj. 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Animal Form</h1>

<form action="" method="post">
  Enter animal:<br>
  <input type="text" name="animal"><br><br>
  <input type="Submit" value="Add Animal">
</form>

<?php
function display()  {
    $animal = $_POST['animal'];
    echo "$animal <br>";
}
if(isset($_POST['animal'])){
    display();
}
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

It currently only displays 1 line at a time and refreshes the line with new input.

Comment: Store them in a session or in a database. Depends for how long you wish to save them for.

Comment: Or if you don't actually care about saving them (the post doesn't make it clear that you do, strictly speaking), then get rid of the PHP completely and just use Javascript.

Comment: store them in session or cookies or database

Comment: or if u want to show complete search history to any user, then database is the best option.

Comment: Append it to a session var and then echo out that var - this may be of help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: What do you mean by go to the line below?  Is this after you send your form?  Please spell out user actions, and expected behaviours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title> Will Proj. 2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
        <h1> Animal Form</h1>

<form action="" method="post">
    Enter animal:<br>
    <?php if(isset($_POST['animal'])){
        foreach($_POST['animal'] as $animal){
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="animal[]" value="'.$animal.'" >';
        }

    } ?>
    <input type="text" name="animal[]"><br><br>
    <input type="Submit" value="Add Animal">
</form>

<?php
function display()  {
        $animals = $_POST['animal'];
        foreach($animals as $animal){
            echo "$animal <br>";
        }
}
if(isset($_POST['animal'])){
        display();
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['animals']) && $_POST['animal']) {
   $_SESSION['animals'] = $_POST['animal'].'<br>';
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['animals']) && $_POST['animal']) {
   $_SESSION['animals'] .= $_POST['animal'].'<br>';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Will Proj. 2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <h1> Animal Form</h1>
   <form action="" method="post">
     Enter animal:<br>
     <input type="text" name="animal"><br><br>
     <input type="Submit" value="Add Animal">
   </form>

   <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['animals']) { echo $_SESSION['animals']; } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will yield undefined index notices when the session is empty, i.e. when you load the page for the first time during this session. Will also yield undefined indexes when the form is not submitted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am doing this for a class assignment and I have not learned the session yet so I dont think im supposed to use this. I was thinking there was a way to use ++ to add vars in the array that then echos them?

Comment: A ++ only increases value eg. if $i=1 and $i++, then $i=2. But it doesn't work with PHP POST, just with JavaScript or jQuery.